# Dayspan JS get an event to happen every second day

Tags: javascript

Trying to get a [dayspan](https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/dayspan) event to happen regardless if it is over a month or year boundary every nth day.

This following snippet shows the boundary problem over a month where I want the event to occur on the 1st of August, but with `dayOfMonth: {every: 2}` it occurs on 30th of July and on the 2nd of August.

I could change [`dayOfMonth`](https://clickermonkey.github.io/dayspan/docs/classes/schedule.html#dayofmonth) to `dayOfYear` however the problem may happen on the 1st of Jan. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
var cal = ds.Calendar.days(6,ds.Day.build(2019, ds.Month.JULY, 31));

cal.addEvent({
    id: 'someUserProvidedId',
    data: " - Every second day",
    schedule: new ds.Schedule({
        dayOfMonth: {every: 2,offset: 0},
        start: ds.Day.build(2019, ds.Month.JULY, 29),
        end: ds.Day.build(2019, ds.Month.AUGUST, 28),
    })
});


cal.days.forEach((i) => {
    console.log(i.format("ddd, MMM Do YYYY"));
    i.events.forEach((j) => {
        console.log(j.event.data);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayspan@1.1.0/dist/dayspan.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted.. I don't see how this can be done (given that `day` confusingly means day-of-week), and I see you've already asked in the [dayspan repo](https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/dayspan/issues/26). Hope the author gives you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this code doesn't use the dayspan plugin, it gets the job done:

```js
var cal = ds.Calendar.days(6,ds.Day.build(2019, ds.Month.JULY, 31));
var counter = 0;

cal.addEvent({
    id: 'someUserProvidedId',
    data: " - Every second day",
    schedule: new ds.Schedule({
        dayOfMonth: {every: 1, offset: 0},
        start: ds.Day.build(2019, ds.Month.JULY, 29),
        end: ds.Day.build(2019, ds.Month.AUGUST, 28),
    })
});


cal.days.forEach((i) => {
    console.log(i.format("ddd, MMM Do YYYY"));
    i.events.forEach((j) => {
        counter++;
        if (counter%2 == 0) {
           console.log(j.event.data);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayspan@1.1.0/dist/dayspan.min.js"></script>
```